# Handlebars.Net Iterate over list [HandlebarsUndefinedBindingException]

Tags: c#, .net, handlebars.js, handlebars.net

I have just started using Handlebars.Net.  I have a template containing:

```
{{#each InvoiceLines}}
   Desc = {{Description}} , Cost = {Cost}}
{{/each}}
```

My data object is as per below:

```
public class Data
{
    public bool IsRenewalInvoice { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLines { get; set; } 
}

public class InvoiceLine
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Cost { get; set; }
}
```

However, I am getting a HandlebarsUndefinedBindingException: 'Description is undefined'.  I have also tried using ***this*** and ***InvoiceLine*** before the property name of the list item as below but that also does not work.

```
Desc = {{this.Description}} , Cost = {this.Cost}}
Desc = {{InvoiceLine.Description}} , Cost = {InvoiceLine.Cost}}
```

How do I get this to work?

Also, if the list is nested in another object within Data - Is it still possible to access the properties of the list item?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be small error in your template: `{Cost}}` instead of `{{Cost}}`.

It should be

```
{{#each InvoiceLines}}
   Desc = {{Description}} , Cost = {{Cost}}
{{/each}}
```

Can you try that ?